# Makefile error no rule found but rule is present

Tags: makefile, compilation, object-files

This Makefile

```
CC = gcc

INC_PATH = -I../common/

SOURCEDIR := ./
SOURCES := $(wildcard $(SOURCEDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIR :=./obj
OBJECTS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.o, $(SOURCES))
DEPENDS := $(patsubst $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIR)/%.d, $(SOURCES))

COMMONDIR     := ../common
SOURCESCOMMON := $(wildcard $(COMMONDIR)/*.c)
OBJDIRCOMMON  := $(COMMONDIR)/obj
OBJECTSCOMMON := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o, $(SOURCESCOMMON))
DEPENDSCOMMON := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.d, $(SOURCESCOMMON))

# ADD MORE WARNINGS!
WARNING := -Wall -Wextra

# OBJS_LOC is in current working directory,
EXECUTABLE := ../server
# .PHONY means these rules get executed even if
# files of those names exist.
.PHONY: all clean

# The first rule is the default, ie. "make",
# "make all" and "make parking" mean the same
all: $(EXECUTABLE)

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJECTS) $(DEPENDS) $(EXECUTABLE)

# Linking the executable from the object files
# $^   # "src.c src.h" (all prerequisites)
$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTSCOMMON) $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) $^ -o $@

-include $(DEPENDS) $(DEPENDSCOMMON)

$(OBJDIR):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIR)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $(INC_PATH) $< -o $@

$(OBJDIRCOMMON):
    mkdir -p $(OBJDIRCOMMON)

$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(SOURCESCOMMON)/%.c | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

is generating the error:

```
 make[1]: *** No rule to make target '../common/obj/utilities.o', needed by '../server'.  Stop.
```

The main rule generating the rule has as input `$(OBJECTSCOMMON)` referring to the objects file `*.o` contained in the directory `OBJDIRCOMMON`. The rule to generate this objects has not explicit target but it is:

```
$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o: $(SOURCESCOMMON)/%.c | $(OBJDIRCOMMON)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $< -o $@
```

and I think this is generating the error. I was expecting the definition `OBJECTSCOMMON := $(patsubst $(COMMONDIR)/%.c,$(OBJDIRCOMMON)/%.o, $(SOURCESCOMMON))` made the rule and valid to generate `$()`

However a similar rule is used to generate `$(OBJECTS)` in the same `Makefile` and it is workin:

```
$(OBJDIR)/%.o: $(SOURCEDIR)/%.c Makefile | $(OBJDIR)
    $(CC) $(WARNING) -MMD -MP -c $(INC_PATH) $< -o $@
```

So why the different behaviour between the rules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$(SOURCESCOMMON)/%.c` expands to `$(wildcard $(COMMONDIR)/*.c)/%.c`, so the pattern will contain something like `../common/utilities.c/%.c` (possibly with a different file name).  This file does not exist, so the pattern rule is ignored.

The other rule uses `$(SOURCEDIR)`, so it does not have this issue.

Comment: Thanks...it worked. I should have looked carefully :)